# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1920,1072) into shape (1920,1080)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

How can I fix this problem with my arrays?

I want to show black and white stripes

```
height = 1920
width = 1080
bitrange = 3
imgs = numpy.zeros((bitrange, height, width), dtype=bool)

for bits in range(0, bitrange):
    stripe_width = width// 2**(bits+1)
    binary = numpy.fromiter(GrayCode(bits+1).generate_gray(), dtype=numpy.int) % 2
    vector = numpy.repeat(binary, stripe_width)
    imgs[bits] = numpy.tile(vector, (height,1))
    window.show(imgs[bits]* 1.0)
```

So, the problem is when I run my program for bitrange 1, 2, 3 it still works.

But from bitrange 4 it does not work with this error message: **could not broadcast input array from shape (1920,1072) into shape (1920,1080)**

Thanks.

Comment: At which line does this error occur? Also, where is `GrayCode()`  imported from?

Comment: at this line:
imgs[bits] = numpy.tile(vector, (height,1))
the grayCode() is  from 
from sympy.combinatorics.graycode import GrayCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1080/(2**(3 + 1)) is 67.5. So for `bit_range = 4`, when `bits = 3`, `stripe_width` is 67, and `vector` has shape `(1080, 1072)` (1072 being `1080//2**4 * 2**4`), which you are trying to assign to `imgs[3]` which has shape `(1920, 1080)`.

This error does not occur for lower values of bits, because 1080 is a multiple of 8, so `1080//n * n` is 1080 for n being 2, 4 or 8.

Since you obtain images of varying size passed a certain valu of bits, a solution would be to store the results in a list:

```
imgs = []
for bit in range(bit_range):
   # ...
   imgs.append(numpy.tile(vector, (height,1)))
```